# Can i get the number of friends the player sent an app invite to?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

- is there a way to get the number of people the player sent an app invite to ?

( we want to reward the player for each app invite he send )

Comment: You are lot allowed to reward anyone for number of invites they send according to Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: As far as I know you can't do it with app invites. You can do it with app requests though.

Comment: @YuraNudelman it is also against policy to reward players on the sending of a game request. You can however reward them for 'request accepts', eg: reward them when they successfully refer someone to your game.